# SQL query with two INNER JOINS throws off HAVING COUNT

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a query in a rails app to look only at care_providers that have at least 3 accepted insurance providers.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ce431/13

```
SELECT `care_providers`.id, name, COUNT(`accepted_insurance_providers`.insurance_provider_id)
  FROM `care_providers`
  INNER JOIN `accepted_insurance_providers` ON `care_providers`.id = `accepted_insurance_providers`.care_provider_id
  GROUP BY `care_providers`.id
  HAVING COUNT(`accepted_insurance_providers`.insurance_provider_id) >=3
  ORDER BY `care_providers`.id ASC
;
```

The fiddle above is how query should work.  It returns only 'Provider 1' as the other providers have fewer than 3 accepted insurance providers.

Of course, there are a number of other conditions I need to make on the query that require an INNER JOIN with other tables.  As soon as I add an additional INNER JOIN my COUNT is thrown off and I get providers in passing my HAVING COUNT criteria that shouldn't.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ce431/12

```
SELECT `care_providers`.id, name, COUNT(`accepted_insurance_providers`.insurance_provider_id)
  FROM `care_providers`
  INNER JOIN `accepted_insurance_providers` ON `care_providers`.id = `accepted_insurance_providers`.care_provider_id
  INNER JOIN `care_providers_coverage_zip_codes` ON `care_providers_coverage_zip_codes`.care_provider_id = `care_providers`.id 
  GROUP BY `care_providers`.id
  HAVING COUNT(`accepted_insurance_providers`.insurance_provider_id) >=3
  ORDER BY `care_providers`.id ASC
;
```

You can see from this fiddle that 'Provider 1' now shows a count of 6 and 'Provider 2' is showing a count of 4.

Any thoughts on how can I structure this to get the count I need?  Bonus thanks if there's an easy way to handle this as a scope in ActiveRecord, but I'll take a SQL answer too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and easy way to fix this -- probably -- is to use `count(distinct)`:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT accepted_insurance_providers.insurance_provider_id) >= 3
```

The problem is that the additional tables being joined in have multiple matches.  This multiplies the number of rows and throws off then count.

Comment: You're my hero!  I knew there had to be a simple solution.